# add a separator image after a paragraph ends

Tags: html, css

I want to add a separator image as a border.

Here's the html

```
    <div class="content-wrapper">
           <div class="container">
               <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-xs-12">
                       <h1>TRACK MY ORDER</h1>
                       <p>Fill your order number below to track your order</p>
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-xs-12">
                       <form action="">
                           <div class="order-input">
                               <input type="text" class="text" placeholder = "Order Number">
                               <input type="submit" class="submit">
                           </div>
                       </form>
                   </div>

                   <div class = "col-xs-12 order-info">
                        <p>Dear Customer, <br><br>
                            Your Order number 19175 has<br>
                            been successfully shipped and here are the tracking details:
                        </p>
                  </div>
                </div>    
            </div>  
       </div>
```

Here's the Css I am trying to have that border.

```
 .order-info p :after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(../assets/gt.png);
    top: 0;
  }
```

This I think should work but strangely not working.

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/z7p5fzzz/1/) this fiddle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couple of things to get this to work:

`.order-info p:after`, no space between `p` and the `:after` pseudoelement.

You don't need the `:after` element to be `position: absolute`. Just put it static and the way `:after` works will do the rest:

```
.order-info p:after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/pcpKrPe.png)!important;
}
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z7p5fzzz/3/

Comment: Damn!

Thank god I put it here instead of trying different things. I would have never noticed that. :P

Comment: how can I start it from the line of `p`?

Comment: What do you mean? @Suraj

Comment: start the separator from the line of the `p`. From the left

Comment: Change your background position: `background-position: center left;`

Comment: and want to extend it till the other end

Comment: Ideally, you would change the image so it's much wider. You can stretch it with CSS (https://jsfiddle.net/z7p5fzzz/8/) but that's generally not a great idea.